# Given a path, find the position on this path by traveled distance

Tags: postgis, point, distance, path

I have a table that consists of a point and a sequence number which forms a path, similar to this:

```
create table path (
  sequence int,
  stop_position geometry(Point, 4326)
);
```

The problem I am facing is finding the resulting point along this path given a specific distance traveled (which is always smaller than the total path distance). I know how to do this using a different programming language like Java, but I was wondering if there is some clever and computationally faster way by utilizing the functionality of the GIS extension.

Here a visual representation of the problem:

[image]

Comment: You want to do a search on [Linear Reference Systems (LRS)](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#Linear_Referencing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostGIS functions you're looking for are [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html) to find the resulting point, [ST_Length](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Length.html) to find the length of the path and [ST_MakeLine](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) to turn the path from a sequence of stop points into a linestring.

The following worked for me:

```
-- make and populate the table with some points
CREATE TABLE my_path (
  pt_sequence int,
  stop_point geometry(Point, 4326)
);
INSERT INTO my_path VALUES
   (1, st_geometryfromtext('POINT(-75.369 40.506)', 4326)),
   (2, st_geometryfromtext('POINT(-75.315 40.504)', 4326)),
   (3, st_geometryfromtext('POINT(-75.207 40.608)', 4326))
;

-- This next line finds the new point in question, assuming the required
-- length is 7500 meters, using st_line_interpolate_point.
-- If you already have your table this is what you need.
SELECT
    'the_point',
    st_line_interpolate_point(
        st_makeline(stop_point ORDER BY pt_sequence), -- this makes the linestring
        7500/
        st_length(
            st_makeline(stop_point ORDER BY pt_sequence)::geography
        ) -- divide your length by the length of the linestring, cast as geography
    ) AS geom
FROM my_path;
```

[image: three point sequence with star at 7500m along path]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ST_LineInterpolatePoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html).

Note that the "distance" in this function is actually a fraction of the total line length, but you can get a linestrings length with [`ST_Length()`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Length.html). See my example below.

```
WITH test_data(geom) AS (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 80, 80 80, 20 40, 40 0)')
)
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, 100/ST_Length(geom)))
FROM test_data
```

Output:

```
st_astext
----------------------------------------
POINT(63.3589941132431 68.9059960754954)
```

[image: output]